# angularjs post data to mvc controller in json format with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project in which I have used angularjs and mvc.I am passing data from angular js controller to my mvc controller by $http.post().For now I am using single object/json array to retreive data like this -public bool UpdateIssueDetails(IssueBO issue).But I want that if I could do like this public public bool UpdateIssueDetails(IssueBO issue,List lstMembersToNotify).I want to send two json arrays from ny angular js controller to my above mvc controller method.

angularjs controller code

```
 $scope.saveIssueDetails = function (issue) {
    var milestoneId = "";
    var milestoneName = "";
    if ($scope.selectedIssue.Milestone== undefined) {
        milestoneId = "";
        milestoneName = "";
    } else {
        milestoneId = $scope.selectedIssue.Milestone.Id;
        milestoneName = $scope.selectedIssue.Milestone.Name;
    }
    var arrMembersToNotify = [];
    var arrMembersToNotifyNew = [];
    var iCount = 0;
    $("#membersToNotify input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        arrMembersToNotify = $(this).val().split("~");
        arrMembersToNotifyNew.push({ "UserId": arrMembersToNotify[0], "UserDisplayName": arrMembersToNotify[1], "Email": arrMembersToNotify[2] });         
    }); 
    var issueDetails =
   {
    Id: issue.Id,
    ProjectId: issue.ProjectId,
    ProjectName: issue.ProjectName,
    IssueStatusId: $scope.selectedIssue.Status.Id,
    StatusName: $scope.selectedIssue.Status.Name,
    IssuePriorityId: $scope.selectedIssue.Priority.Id,
    PriorityName: $scope.selectedIssue.Priority.Name,
    AssignedUserId: $scope.selectedIssue.AssignedTo.Id,
    AssigneeDisplayName: $scope.selectedIssue.AssignedTo.DisplayName,
    IssueCategoryId: $scope.selectedIssue.Category.Id,
    CategoryName: $scope.selectedIssue.Category.Name,
    DueDate: $scope.selectedIssue.DueDate,
    OwnerUserId: $scope.selectedIssue.OwnedBy.Id,
    OwnerDisplayName: $scope.selectedIssue.OwnedBy.DisplayName,
    IssueTypeId: $scope.selectedIssue.Type.Id,
    IssueTypeName: $scope.selectedIssue.Type.Name,
    IssueResolutionId: $scope.selectedIssue.Resolution.Id,
    ResolutionName: $scope.selectedIssue.Resolution.Name,
    MilestoneId: milestoneId,
    MilestoneName: milestoneName,
    Estimation: $scope.selectedIssue.Estimation,
    Progress: $scope.selectedIssue.Progress,
   };
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/Issues' + '/UpdateIssueDetails/';
    $http.post(url, [issueDetails, arrMembersToNotifyNew]).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data != '' || data.length >= 0 || data == true) {
            //$scope.selectedIssue = issue;
            //$scope.showIssueDetails($scope.selectedIssue);
            $scope.GetAssignedIssues();
        }
        else if (data == '' || data == false) {
            $scope.selectedIssue = null;
        } else {
            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
        }
    });
};
```

mvc controller code

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AuthenticationRequired]
    public bool UpdateIssueDetails(IssueBO issue,List<IssueNotification> lstMembersToNotify)
    {
        try
        {
            //var issueDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(issueAllDetails[0].ToString());
            //List<Dictionary<string, string>> membersToNotifyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(issueAllDetails[1].ToString());
            var membersToNotify = lstMembersToNotify.Select(membersToNotifyDetail =>
                                                                new IssueNotification()
                                                                {
                                                                    UserId =membersToNotifyDetail.UserId,
                                                                    Email =
                                                                        membersToNotifyDetail.Email,
                                                                    UserDisplayName =
                                                                        membersToNotifyDetail.UserDisplayName
                                                                }).ToList();
            var newIssue = new IssueBO
            {
                OwnerUserId = issue.OwnerUserId,
                OwnerDisplayName = issue.OwnerDisplayName,
                LastUpdatedUserId = SessionItems.UserId,
                LastUpdaterDisplayName = SessionItems.DisplayName,
                LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                ProjectId = issue.ProjectId,
                ProjectName = issue.ProjectName,
                Id = issue.Id,
                AssignedUserId = issue.AssignedUserId,
                AssigneeDisplayName = issue.AssigneeDisplayName,
                IssueStatusId = issue.IssueStatusId,
                StatusName = issue.StatusName,
                Progress = issue.Progress,
                IssuePriorityId = issue.IssuePriorityId,
                PriorityName = issue.PriorityName,
                IssueTypeId = issue.IssueTypeId,
                IssueTypeName = issue.IssueTypeName,
                IssueCategoryId = issue.IssueCategoryId,
                CategoryName = issue.CategoryName,
                IssueResolutionId = issue.IssueResolutionId,
                ResolutionName = issue.ResolutionName,
                DueDate = issue.DueDate,
                Estimation = issue.Estimation,
                MilestoneId = issue.MilestoneId,
                MilestoneName = issue.MilestoneName
            };
            var result = BLL.AdminLayer.UpdateIssueDetail(newIssue, membersToNotify);
            return result.IsSuccessful && result.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BLL.Base.BaseLayer.WriteApplicationLog(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am passing two json array from my angularjs controller like this-$http.post(url, [issueDetails, arrMembersToNotifyNew]).success(function (data, status, headers, config).But I am getting error trying this.Please suggest how to achieve this.Thanks

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data to the action by using `JSON.stringify()`

```
$http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ issue: issueDetails, 
     lstMembersToNotify: arrMembersToNotifyNew 
});
```

Comment: If he stringify's the object, won't he have to deserialize it? In which case, wouldn't sending it as an object be enough?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh  we need to `[FromBody]` annotation in front of action parameter of controller...that would not lead to do `stringify()`  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Post it as properties of an object.

```
$http.post(url, { issue: issueDetails, lstMembersToNotify: arrMembersToNotifyNew });
```

Comment: still not working getting this error-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Debug the asp.net controller method. 500 usually means an exception was thrown on the server.